# replace specific lines of two files

Tags: cmd

alright.
i have two files
file1 and file2

file1

```
line1
helloa
hellob
line2
```

file2

```
line3
helloc
hellod
helloe
line4
```

i want to replace all the `hello` lines in file1 with that of file2, the lines are together, any ideas?

can it be done using this statement?

```
for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%a in ('find "hello" ^< file2') do set helloa=%%b
```

thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: "can it be done using this statement?" - erm, what happened when you ran it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal
for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%i in ('^<file2.txt findstr /n "hello"') do set "#%%i=%%j"
(for /f "delims=" %%i in (file1.txt) do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    if not "!line!"=="!line:hello=!" (
        endlocal
        if not defined flag (
            for /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a in ('set "#"') do echo(%%b
            set "flag=true"
        )
    ) else ( 
        echo(!line!
        endlocal
    )
))>output.txt
```

output is in `output.txt`.

Edit: improved behaviour concerning `delayed expansion`.

Comment: what does # in `#%%i=%%j` do? or is it just to give a name to it?

Comment: `#%%i` are the names of the variables with the "hallo"s from `file2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "inserted=N"
(
FOR /f %%i IN (file1.) DO (
 ECHO %%i|findstr /b /i "hello" >NUL
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO(%%i) ELSE (
  IF DEFINED inserted (
   SET "inserted="
   FINDSTR /b /i "hello" <file2.
  )
 )
)
)>output.txt
GOTO :EOF
```

The flag `inserted` is set to any value.
Read each line of file1.
 - if the line does not begin 'hello' then just ECHO it
 - if the line begins 'hello' then
   * if the flag is set, clear it and output the lines from file2. that begin 'hello'
   * if the flag is not set, do nothing (which skips the remainder of file1.'s 'hello' lines